# Spring JPA Tuple not serializable

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring Boot 2.3 application. I use Spring JPA to make queries to Mysql. I also take advantage of Redis.

```
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "documents#chartrevenuebymonthperuser")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("Here there is my query")
    List<Tuple> chartRevenueByMonthPerUser(@Param("from") LocalDate from, @Param("until") LocalDate until, @Nullable @Param("storeId") Long storeId);
```

I like more `List<Tuple>` rather than `List<Object[]>` but unfortunately Redis says that Tuple is not serializable.
Tuple is from package `javax.persistence`
Do you have any good advice to take advantage of Tuple allowing Redis to cache the results?

Comment: Is Tuple your own class/interface or from some other library? Provide complete details for the Tuple.

Comment: @sonus21 You are right, sorry. javax.persistence.Tuple

Answer (score 0):

Redis cache can be configured to use other serializers/deserializer.

Tuple interface does not provide any getter/setter etc so serialization is failing, though you can define your Tuple that should implement Tuple interface.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class TupleMsg implements Tuple {
  private Object[] tuple;

  @Override
  public <T> T get(int i, Class<T> type) {
    final Object result = get(i);
    if (result != null && !type.isInstance(result)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          String.format(
              "Requested tuple value [index=%s, realType=%s] cannot be assigned to requested type [%s]",
              i, result.getClass().getName(), type.getName()));
    }
    return (T) result;
  }

  @Override
  public Object get(int i) {
    if (i < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("requested tuple index must be greater than zero");
    }
    if (i >= tuple.length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("requested tuple index exceeds actual tuple size");
    }
    return tuple[i];
  }

  @Override
  public Object[] toArray() {
    return tuple;
  }
  
  @Override
  public <X> X get(TupleElement<X> tupleElement) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  @Override
  public <X> X get(String alias, Class<X> type) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  @Override
  public Object get(String alias) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  @Override
  public List<TupleElement<?>> getElements() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Some of the methods in this interface has not been implemented,  you can implement them if you think you need them.

```
class MyRedisSerializer implements RedisSerializer<Object> {
    private GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer =
        new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();

   
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(Object t) throws SerializationException {
      if (t instanceof Tuple) {
        TupleMsg msg = new TupleMsg(((Tuple) t).toArray());
        return jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(msg);
      }
      return jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(t);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
      if (SerializationUtils.isEmpty(bytes)) {
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(bytes);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Jackson deserialization has failed {}", new String(bytes), e);
        return new String(bytes);
      }
    }
  }
```

Once you have implementation for Tuple and RedisSerializer you can use them to configure cache.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheManagerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager redisCacheManager() {
        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair<Object> jsonSerializer = 
         RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new MyRedisSerializer());
         return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder
                .fromConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(
                    RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                            .entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(1))
                            .serializeValuesWith(jsonSerializer)
                )
                .build();
    }

}
```

That's all you need to get this working.